# Какие пунктуационные правила использованы в предложении?

Tags: правила

### Объясните, пожалуйста, пунктуационные правила, которые применяются в предложении.

*Одним из следующих шагов является повсеместное внедрение разнообразных датчиков, т. н. сенсоров, с помощью которых программные средства могут распознавать деятельность и состояние человека, при этом способствуя повышению эффективности данной деятельности.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Объясните, пожалуйста, пунктуационные правила которые применяются в
>   предложении.

---

> Одним из следующих шагов является повсеместное внедрение разнообразных
>   датчиков, т. н. сенсоров, с помощью которых программные средства могут
>   распознавать деятельность и состояние человека, при этом способствуя
>   повышению эффективности данной деятельности.

В вопросе после "правила" желательно поставить запятую - начинается придаточное определительное в СПП.

В предложении после слова "датчиков" ставится вопрос  - каких? - сенсоров, это будет приложение (определение, выраженное существительным).

Далее идёт придаточное определительное предложение в СПП, оно отвечает на вопрос КАКИХ? Сенсоров - каких? - с помощью которых...

В составе этого придаточного имеется обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом: *при этом способствуя...* Его тоже следует отделить запятой.
В данном предложении использованы следующие пунктуационные правила:
1)запятые в сложном предложении, 2)знаки препинания при обособленном обстоятельстве, знаки препинания при обособленном определении (приложении)

Comment: В предложении использованы следующие пунктуационные правила:

Comment: датчиков, т. н. сенсоров, - пояснение, а не приложение, потому то здесь одно и то же название другими словами, а не характеристика датчиков.Приложением было бы "внедрение сенсоров, чувствительных датчиков,..."